# How to install pdo_ibm on Centos 7 php71

Tags: php, db2

I am trying to install IBM DB2 PDO module for php71 on Centos 7 64 bit.

When run the following command I get the subsequent error:

```
[root@5707f11aa698 dsdriver]# pecl install pdo_ibm
pecl.php.net is using a unsupported protocol - This should never happen.
pecl/PDO_IBM requires package "pear/PDO"
No valid packages found
install failed
[root@5707f11aa698 dsdriver]# uname -a
Linux 5707f11aa698 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs #1 SMP Wed Mar 14 15:12:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am running this in my Docker conatiner.

I was able to install ibm_db2 with the following command:

```
pecl install ibm_db2
```

Please assist in installing pdo_ibm

Comment: Did you try installing packages php-pear and php-dev before running the pdo_ibm install ?

Comment: Yes they are installed. I was able to run "pecl install ibm_db2"

Comment: The last time that I used PDO_IBM on Centos was with PHP 7.0.23 and PDO_IBM v1.3.4-patched.  At that time it was necessary to compile pdo_ibm from source, following the directions at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.php.doc/doc/t0011926.html . I notice the current version of PDO_IBM is now 1.3.5.  You might try building from source.

Comment: Correction. My Centos 7.5 (physical) used php 5.4.16 with PDO 1.3.4.  When I upgraded from PHP 5.4 to PHP 7.1, then I can recreate your symptom when using `pecl install pdo_ibm`.  I see also an old bug matching this https://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-bugs/2012-02/msg01335.html but for opensuse. More investigation needed.

Comment: On Centos 7.5 (physical) with PHP v7.1.18 and PDO_IBM v1.3.5 I was able to compile PDO_IBM from source only after hacking ibm_driver.c to avoid a compilation error. The resulting PDO_IBM module allowed a connection to local and remote Db2 databases. It seems the developers of PDO_IBM may need to make a new version that properly works with PHP 7.1 and compiles/runs without errors or warnings on Centos. Might be worth raising an issue on github. Looks like a code defect to me, so stackoverflow might not be best channel.

Comment: Thanks @mao I will do so.